# How to bind a ListView to an ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int,object>> inside a ViewModel in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Something like this:

```
public class EffectViewModel
{
    public string Name ...

    ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int,object>> settings
    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int,object>> Settings
    {
        get {return this.settings;}
        set
        {
            this.settings = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged ( "Settings" );
        }
    }
}
```

Right now I am trying to bind it like this:

`EffectWindowViewModel.Effects` is of type `ObservableCollection<EffectViewModel>`.

```
<ListView Width="1000"
            Height="600"
            ItemsSource="{Binding EffectWindowViewModel.Effects}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key}"
                            Header="Name" />

            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"
                            Header="Value" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

But I don't know how to specify `.Settings` property.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't see how an `ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int,object>>` has any advantages over a `ObservableCollection<Tuple<int,object>>`. The solution should be about the same though.

Comment: It doesn't. I didn't think of using Tuple in this case. But feel free. I just don't know how I would bind in that case either though.

Comment: And Settings is a Sibling of Effects, so this doesn't look like it's going to work.

Comment: Why? So it can not be data binded?

Comment: check your output window for binding errors. btw shouldnt the binding be: ItemsSource="{Binding Settings}"? cause its the name of your property. and your dataconext or source of your listview should be an instance of EffectViewModel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your actual binding will not work cause EffectViewModel has no key and Value Property. i really dont know what your listview should display. if you want a list of EffectViewModels then the Itemssource is right. if you want further for each EffectViewModel to display the settings. then you need somekind of itemsscontrol with Itemssource={Binding Settings}. this itemsscontrol of course will need a itemsstemplate with your Key and Value.

i have no VS here atm, but your GridViewColumn needs a kind of CellTemplate. and this template should consist of a itemscontrol. because you have 2collections!
this code is probably not right but should take you in the right direction

```
<ListView Width="1000"
        Height="600"
        ItemsSource="{Binding EffectWindowViewModel.Effects}">
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Settings}">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplatex:Key="myCell4Settings">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding.}">
             <ListView.View>
             <GridView>
              <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key}"
                        Header="Name" />

                <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"
                        Header="Value" />
          </GridView>
         </ListView.View>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
       </GridViewColumn>
    </ListView>
  </DataTemplate>
 </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

btw you could also use 2 lists independent. one parent Combobox or listbox (x:Name=parent) with itemssource=EffectWindowViewModel.Effects and a second ListView like you have, with the itemssource binding:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=parent, Path=SelectedItem.Settings}"
```

Comment: Can you please show an example for this? I also want to set the ItemsSource to Settings but then how am I gonna specify that it's inside EffectWindowViewModel.Effects (for each instance)?

Comment: But your observation is right, I want further for each EffectViewModel  to display the settings.

Comment: Thanks blindmeis, btw what does it mean when you said "<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding.}">"? I don't know what the "Binding." signifies there?

Comment: this just means you bind to the current source. here are some more infos http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Settings, Path=EffectWindowViewModel.Effects}"
```

Comment: It says expected '}' on the h character of Path.

Comment: Was missing a comma before "Path". Try it now.

Comment: When I ran it returned this: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=Settings'. BindingExpression:Path=EffectWindowViewModel.Effects; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListView' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: look at my answer. your GridViewColumn bindings are too "early" you miss that the Settings Property is a Collection of your EffectViewModel and not a Property of EffectWindowViewModel.Effects

Comment: How do you mean? Settings is a property for each instance of EffectViewModel, which is stored in the Effects collection.

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Effects.Settings}" should work if your DataContext is set to an instance of EffectWindowViewModel.

Comment: Thanks, I ran that now, and got this: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Settings' property not found on 'object' ''ObservableCollection`1' (HashCode=34810426)'. BindingExpression:Path=Effects.Settings; DataItem='EffectWindowViewModel' (HashCode=43248677); target element is 'ListView' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: like i said you have two collections (Effects and settings) but just one itemsscontrol your listview. you need a second one for your settings.

Comment: Thanks blindmeis, but I don't know how to do that. Can you please show?

Comment: Btw doing this seems to work as in there is no binding error: DataContext="{Binding EffectWindowViewModel.Effects}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Settings}"